# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'

Tags: python-3.x, dnf

When I point my python3 bin to /usr/bin/python3.6 I get below error:

```
[dgaikwad@localhost iqe-core]$ dnf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'
[dgaikwad@localhost iqe-core]$
```

It is works fine when python3 pointed to /usr/bin/python3.7

Can someone please help me to solve it?

Comment: This other post is possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894712/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-dnf-when-running-yum-or-dnf

Comment: Packages are installed per interpreter. If you installed ``dnf`` for ``/usr/bin/python3.7``, it's not automatically installed for ``/usr/bin/python3.6``-