# Since downgrading my python version on fedora my dnf don't work anymore could someone help me?

Tags: python, linux, installation, fedora, dnf

Today I downgrade my python version from 3.10.0 to 3.9.16 and I tried using dnf and got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 61, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'
```

Then I tried doing

```
pip uninstall dnf
```

And I now always got this error

```
/usr/bin/env: ā: No such file or directory
```

Could someone help me ?

I tried google , chatgpt and I search to a lot of stackoverflow I even got the pip uninstall dnf
from there [link of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65481153)

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: This is  not a good solution, because it overwrites one python version with another.